# How to add paragraph wise texts separated by vertical line into itextsharp created PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a requirement where i need to divide the newly created PDF file into two parts separated  by vertical line.Now as per my requirement i have to add texts into the new PDF paragraph wise means at first all the records should go to paragraph one and one its over it should show into second paragraph from the top.

Here is the code that i am trying to do with ,but i am getting vertical line in only half portion of the PDF.And i am totally unaware of how to add the texts paragraph wise.

```
public static void paraPDF(string pdffile){

   Document pdfDoc = new Document();
   PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(pdffile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));

   pdfDoc.Open();
   pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Some Text added"));
   PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
   cb.MoveTo(pdfDoc.PageSize.Width / 2, pdfDoc.PageSize.Height / 2);
   cb.LineTo(pdfDoc.PageSize.Width / 2, pdfDoc.PageSize.Height);
   cb.Stroke();

   pdfDoc.Close();

   Console.WriteLine("The file was created.");
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Please help me..

Comment: Please search for examples that use the `ColumnText` object. You have phrased a very simple question *"How do I display `Paragraph` objects in 2 columns on one page?"* in such a convoluted way that nobody understands what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume that you want to add paragraphs into columns the way it's done in this PDF: [column_paragraphs.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/column_paragraphs.pdf).

In that case, you'd define two columns, one for each half of the page. For instance `new Rectangle(36, 36, 290, 806)` for the left half and `new Rectangle(305, 36, 559, 806)` for the right half. Suppose that these are two values in a `COLUMNS` array.

You would then use this `COLUMNS` array to position a `ColumnText` object. In Java, this would look like this:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
int side_of_the_page = 0;
ct.setSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);
int paragraphs = 0;
while (paragraphs < 30) {
    ct.addElement(new Paragraph(String.format("Paragraph %s: %s", ++paragraphs, TEXT)));
    while (ColumnText.hasMoreText(ct.go())) {
        if (side_of_the_page == 0) {
            side_of_the_page = 1;
            canvas.moveTo(297.5f, 36);
            canvas.lineTo(297.5f, 806);
            canvas.stroke();
        }
        else {
            side_of_the_page = 0;
            document.newPage();
        }
        ct.setSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);
    }
}
```

When the value of `side_of_the_page` is 0, you're working on the left side of the page, and you need to draw a line when you switch to the right side. When the value of `side_of_the_page` is 1, you're working on the right side of the page, and you need to go to a new page before you switch to the left side again.

I know that you're working in C#, but please look at the Java code as if it were pseudo-code. The C# code is very similar. For more info, please take a look at the other `ColumnText` examples from [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book/) (I'm the original developer who wrote iText). For the corresponding C# examples, please use [this link](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/178).

Comment: @Will You please post the c# code  as i am not able to get the write methods to do it using c#.\

Comment: I don't know how to write C#. Please clarify which methods you can't find.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in C#, although it is not going over to the second column, for some reason, the **HasMoreText(ct.Go())** is always false? @Bruno, any ideas on what I can do?

```
  var doc = new Document();
        var pdf = "D:/Temp/pdfs/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyymmdd") + ".pdf"; // mm ??

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdf, FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
        int side_of_the_page = 0;
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);
        int paragraphs = 0;
        while (paragraphs < 30)
        {
            ct.AddElement(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(String.Format("Paragraph %s: %s", ++paragraphs, "SOME STUFF")));
            while (ColumnText.HasMoreText(ct.Go()))
            {
                if (side_of_the_page == 0)
                {
                    side_of_the_page = 1;
                    canvas.MoveTo(297.5f, 36);
                    canvas.LineTo(297.5f, 806);
                    canvas.Stroke();
                }
                else
                {
                    side_of_the_page = 0;
                    doc.NewPage();
                }
                ct.SetSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);
            }
        }
        doc.Close();
```